# Is there an event for when I click the ListView where there is no item?

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, events, xamarin.android

I basically want to do something when clicking a ListView where there is no item, so I don't want to use the ListView.ItemClick Event Handler. When I try to use ListView.Click it tells me that I have to use item click. Any help?
I tried Lucas's solution this way:

```html
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lvQueue"/>
<ListView.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer
        Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped"
        NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
</ListView.GestureRecognizers>
```

and also this way:

```html
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lvQueue">
    <ListView.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer
        Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped"
        NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
</ListView.GestureRecognizers>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: From what I understood, you are trying to get the click on the ListView, and not on the ListView Items correct? if not care to explain

Comment: yes, I am trying to click on the ListView but on the items.

Comment: so what's wrong with Lucas anwser then? he showed you how to get the click on the listview, did you put an breakpoint where the event starts to see if it hits?

Comment: there is an error showing in the xaml file when im trying it

Comment: I have added an edit

Comment: are you using Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.Android?

Comment: Xamarin.Android

Comment: then add the tag for Xamarin.Android to avoid confusion

Comment: Okay added, do you know the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `TapGestureRecognizer` on the ListView

#### in Xml

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lvQueue"/>
```

#### in Code behind

```
ListView listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lvQueue); ;
listView.SetOnTouchListener(new GestureListener());
```

```
public class GestureListener : Java.Lang.Object, View.IOnTouchListener
{
    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {

        // do something you want

        return true;
    }
}
```

### Update

Because the touch event will always been invoked before item click action, so if you do want to only add click event on white space of the page when the items of `ListView` is few . We could define another View below the listview and set the click event as a workaround.

#### in xml

Put the ListView in a LinearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">



        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    <TextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"   // set the weight as 1 , so that it will warp the white space of the screen auto
         android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"  // set the background color the same with thelistview
         android:id="@+id/view"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

#### in code behind

```
TextView view = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.view);
view.Click += View_Click;
```

```
private void View_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //...          
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me... I added it and I got a message saying that I need layout_width and layout_height

Comment: Thank you that worked for me partly, the OnTouch method also occurs when I click an item inside the listview. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: The Touch event overrides the ItemClick, is there any way to fix that?